# Unable to execute query in PHP

Tags: php

I have a SQL query which works perfectly if I am running it manually through PhpMyAdmin, however, it is unable to execute when executing from PHP.

Query:

```
LOCK TABLE table_name WRITE;

SELECT @myRight := rgt FROM table_name
WHERE name = 'feildname';

UPDATE table_name SET rgt = rgt + 2 WHERE rgt > @myRight;
UPDATE table_name SET lft = lft + 2 WHERE lft > @myRight;

INSERT INTO table_name(name, lft, rgt) VALUES('new_feild_value', @myRight + 1, @myRight + 2);

UNLOCK TABLES;
```

I want to run the query through my PHP page which has `new_feild_value` variable taken from user input, which can be seen in the code below:

```
<?php
$newname = $_POST['newname'];
$sqlquery = 'LOCK TABLE table_name WRITE;

    SELECT @myRight := rgt FROM table_name
    WHERE name = "feildname";

    UPDATE table_name SET rgt = rgt + 2 WHERE rgt > @myRight;
    UPDATE table_name SET lft = lft + 2 WHERE lft > @myRight;

    INSERT INTO table_name(name, lft, rgt) VALUES("' .$newname . '", @myRight + 1, @myRight + 2);

    UNLOCK TABLES;';
if(!mysqli_query($link,$sqlquery)){ //$link is variable to make sql connection
                echo 'error inserting the comment';
            exit();
            }
 echo 'successfully inserted the values';
?>
```

The PHP snippet above won't work, but for the same snippet, other simple queries are working. What is the issue and how can I fix it?

Comment: Read up on how to use [PDO](http://www.php.net/manual/en/pdo.prepared-statements.php).  They are becoming the norm in database interaction in PHP.

Comment: Also, use [`mysqli_error()`](http://www.php.net/manual/en/mysqli.error.php) to see what the error message is when your query fails.

Comment: It says- `You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'UPDATE nested_category SET rgt = rgt + 2 WHERE rgt > @myLeft; UPDATE nested_cate' at line 1` for `nested_category` is my table name

Comment: As the upvoted answer says, you cannot run multiple queries in one statement.  You should follow what the manual says with multi-query.

Answer (score 4):

You must use mysqli_multi_query to run multiple queries in one statement with mysqli. http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli.multi-query.php